# Почему связка Laravel Gate и Policy при авторизации в сообщении возвращает NULL?

Tags: php, laravel, авторизация, laravel-gate, laravel-policy

В приложении Laravel 10 использую авторизацию действий при помощи `Gate`, `Policy` и `Spatie`. Сама авторизация события отрабатывает нормально, то есть куда нужно и кого нужно пускает и не пускает соответственно.

Однако возникла небольшая проблема со следующим кейсом: пользователь не админ, привилегий никак не имеет, соответственно, метод `before` возвращает `false` на проверку роли администратора. Далее должна запускаться проверка в методе `canEditStatus`, откуда должен вернуться ответ с кодом и сообщением ошибки, так как, повторюсь, привилегий у пользователя нет. Вместо сообщения и кода возвращается `NULL`, хоть проверка действительно не прошла.

Ниже привожу исходники с политикой, контроллером и ответом в Postman.

> \app\Policies\UserPolicy.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    private const ACCESS_ALLOW_MESSAGE = 'Ok';

    private const ACCESS_DENIED_MESSAGE = 'Access denied';

    public function before(User $user): bool
    {
        return $user->hasRole('admin'); // <-- не проходит, все верно
    }

    public function canEditStatus(User $user): Response
    {
        if ($user->hasPermissionTo('edit status')) {
            return $this->allow(self::ACCESS_ALLOW_MESSAGE, 200);
        } else {
            return $this->deny(self::ACCESS_DENIED_MESSAGE, 403); // <-- ожидаю этот ответ
        }
    }
}
```

> \app\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Requests\Api\UserUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\RecordsNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class UserController extends ApiController
{
    public function update(UserUpdateRequest $updateRequest, string $id): JsonResponse
    {
        if ($updateRequest->has('is_active')) {
            $authorize = Gate::inspect('can-edit-status', User::class);
            if ($authorize->denied()) {
                dd($authorize); // <-- дамп результата авторизации
                abort($authorize->code(), $authorize->message());
            }
        }

        // дальше логика обновления
    }
}
```

Ну и, собственно, ответ на запрос из Postman'а:
[image: Ответ на запрос из Postman'а]